# Find method does not work in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, find, laravel-5

I have controller like this

```
 $test= test::find($id);  
 return $test;
```

return `null` but when I change it to :

```
 $test= test::where('id',$id)->get();
 return $test;
```

return all value of `$test`.

My migration is :

```
 Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user', 20);
 })
```

This is my model:

```
 public $fillable = [
    'user'
  ];
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about your code? Post the model code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
I have  `protected $primaryKey='user'` in my model and I change it to  `protected $primaryKey = 'id'`;

Answer (score 2):

You need a model class. That corresponds to the migration. And it has to be imported in your controller if it's not in the default paths.

[Use the below command and it till generate the template and model. Laravel 5.1+](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent)

`php artisan make:model User --migration`

Comment: @paranoid add complete files.